# Unable to log-in to workbench

Tags: sandbox, workbench

I access workbench for sandbox in the following way....

1. Log in to salesforce sandbox account in 1 tab
2. In another tab, I open https://workbench.developerforce.com/ and I get this window...

[image]
 3. This takes me to workbench.

But lately I'm unable to access workbench. On clicking the **Login with Salesforce** button in workbench, I am redirected to Salesforce sandbox account instead and not to workbench.

What's the correct way to access workbench? Am I missing something?

Comment: got my-domain on your production org ? that sometimes starts messing things up because you're trying to log in to the wrong instance.

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke Yes it does contain "my" xxx.my.salesforce.com/001/o

Comment: I have seen this issue as well.  It's not related to workbench, this problem occurs intermittently with any app using OAuth against an org with custom domain.  A workaround I use is to not be logged into the org before you try using workbench and to use the "Login to a custom domain" link when logging in to workbench.

Comment: Yea, I think "login.salesforce.com" will redirect you to your mydomain login based on a cookie. That's probably based on the assumption most users only use a single org, but highly inconvenient if you have access to several orgs. I think Anup's answer should work.

Answer (score 5):

Clearing cache would resolved your issue. I did resolved this by clearing cache and browser history.

Comment: UPDATE: Deleted the previos comment. It's not working again. Once I log in from workbench, I'm redirected to the sandbox default page :(

Answer (score 4):

I am also facing the same issue. I resolved this by following steps-
when you go to Workbench and select Sandbox, you get re-directed to test.salesforce.com where you get prompted for your password. Try changing the beginning of URL from test to csX, where X is your Sandbox instance (e.g. cs2.salesforce.com) and press enter. Now login and your workbench home page will be displayed.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your comment @anup. FYI idea isn't working :(

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. And I solved the issue by replacing the URL with Domain Name of the SF instance.
So after you get re-directed to test.salesforce.com with prompting User ID and Password. Try to replace the URL with the Domain name of the SF instance (e.g. 
ABCD--UAT.cs12.my.salesforce.com ).
It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue when as System Administrator I logged in as another user. After creating a new user in Salesforce and logging in directly the issue disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I had issues logging into my developer org.  Here is how I resolved

1.) logged out of developer org in browser window(s)
2.) from initial workbench login screen, selected "production" type org
3.) logged in using my developer orgs username and password